# How to create desktop widgets

Tags: css, desktop, widget

Hy everyone, i am trying to build a desktop widgets o a web application for a school projects using XHTML, CSS, JavaScript and Ajax. My question is:

Anyone know any toolkit or framework or something to build desktop widgets?

Thank you!

[EDIT]
Hy guys, i know i asked this question 10 months ago, but i figure out how to build those apps with html/css/javascript. It is simple, the answers is that you need to create a zip archive when you finished it and just add the widget into win7 widgets.

I am sorry for the question i asked 10 months ago, but i think this info should be shared now with a lot of people who might have this problem!

Comment: @hakre I am sorry because i am trying to learn something! I will not post any other question about this subject, because i will get everything closed everytime! I am sorry if i disturbed anyone! I really am!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for the [Adobe Air](http://get.adobe.com/air/?promoid=JOPDE) to create the desktop widgets.

> The Adobe® AIR® 3 runtime enables developers to use HTML, JavaScript,
>   Adobe Flash® software, and ActionScript® to build web applications
>   that run as standalone client applications without the constraints of
>   a browser.

Comment: I understand that. But the project mentioned that i need to build a desktop widget, not an app. For an desktop app i could use JavaFX! Thanks anyway foe your answer!